# List comprehension vs loop - what do i not understand?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, list-comprehension

I'm a little confused why my list comprehension is working, but not my for-loop.

Can someone explain what I'm missing here?

```
sales = ['$1.21', '$7.29', '$12.52', '$5.13', '$20.39', '$30.82', '$1.85', '$17.98']
# When for-loop
loop_sales =[]
for sale in sales:
    sale.strip("$")
    loop_sales.append(sale)
print(loop_sales)
```

Output: ['$1.21', '$7.29', '$12.52', '$5.13', '$20.39', '$30.82', '$1.85', '$17.98']

```
# When list comprehension
list_sales = [sale.strip("$") for sale in sales]
print(list_sales)
```

Output: ['1.21', '7.29', '12.52', '5.13', '20.39', '30.82', '1.85', '17.98']

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`strip` method just returns a new value (which is the processed output actually), It does not change the `sale` variable here at all. In order to make it work, try `sale = sale.strip("$")` instead of `sale.strip("$")` in your normal for loop code or just use `loop_sales.append(sale.strip('$'))` as Talha Tayyab said in his answer

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
sales = ['$1.21', '$7.29', '$12.52', '$5.13', '$20.39', '$30.82', '$1.85', '$17.98']
# When for-loop
loop_sales =[]
for sale in sales:
    loop_sales.append(sale.strip("$"))
print(loop_sales)
#output
['1.21', '7.29', '12.52', '5.13', '20.39', '30.82', '1.85', '17.98']
```

Answer (score 2):

As a method, `strip` does not change the string itself, it just returns a stripped version of the string. So you can approach this in 2 ways. Either save the returned string as a variable and append that variable or append `sales.strip($)`

so like this:
version 1 (saving as variable):

```
sales = ['$1.21', '$7.29', '$12.52', '$5.13', '$20.39', '$30.82', '$1.85', '$17.98']
# When for-loop
loop_sales =[]
for sale in sales:
    a= sale.strip("$")
    loop_sales.append(a)
print(loop_sales)
```

or version 2:

```
sales = ['$1.21', '$7.29', '$12.52', '$5.13', '$20.39', '$30.82', '$1.85', '$17.98']
# When for-loop
loop_sales =[]
for sale in sales:
    loop_sales.append(sale.strip("$"))
print(loop_sales)
```

This all depends on whether or not you will use the variable later on in the code but I think the second version is better if not.

Answer (score 1):

`strip` doesn't *change* the string, it returns the stripped string.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```py
loop_sales =[]
for sale in sales:
    loop_sales.append(sale.strip("$"))
print(loop_sales)
```

Comment: insert code within a code block will be better, or the code maybe collapse into one lint